# Telling what version of browser is being used + if screen reader is being used

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is there a way to tell which version of a browser (which browser) someone is using, and if they are using a screen reader?

I am making a website, literally, for everyone. I was thinking of making a super cool looking JS/AJAX/PHP Website for the "first world" countries and a plain HTML-CSS for the "third world".

I need to tell what browser and what version of the browser is being used, so that i know which site to load, as well as be able to see if the user is using some kind of Screen Reader. That way the server can either load the mega cool Website with all the sprinkles, or a basic Screen Reader Friendly site for the invalid.

I have a good base of knowledge in PHP/JS but have no clue how to go about with this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: third world countries don't have javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the navigator object to detect client's browser. Because we cannot always trust the user-agent.

JavaScript Part:

```
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"

if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent

else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome"

else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version"

else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1)
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox"

else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent

else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) <
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) )
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}

// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present

if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
 fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
 majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}

document.write(''
 +'Browser name  = '+browserName+'<br>'
 +'Full version  = '+fullVersion+'<br>'
 +'Major version = '+majorVersion+'<br>'
 +'navigator.appName = '+navigator.appName+'<br>'
 +'navigator.userAgent = '+navigator.userAgent+'<br>'
)
```

See the demo here..http://jsfiddle.net/hw4jM/3/

Regarding screen reader there is a better answer here in stackoverflow..https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712758/3222041

Comment: Thank you very much :) :) like seriously, thanks ALOT :)

Comment: hi @EmirMasic that's great to hear that this helped you..